# ffmpeg image sequence slideshow with fade - missing images?

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg, images

This is using ffmpeg version 3.4.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 on Ubuntu 18.04.

I'd like to achieve the same as in [Create video with 5 images with fadeIn/out effect in ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/833232/create-video-with-5-images-with-fadein-out-effect-in-ffmpeg) (mostly "Dip to black", although I'd like to know about "Crossfade" too) - however, I have many files, and would prefer to use absolute paths, and I'm afraid I'll run into some command line limitation if I list each file on the command line.

So, I've found this ( the same is noted on [ffmpeg slideshow with crossfade](https://superuser.com/questions/1265642/ffmpeg-slideshow-with-crossfade) ):

- https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/FFMPEG_An_Intermediate_Guide/image_sequence#Slideshow_with_crossfading_between_the_pictures

... which mentions:

> "A" is the duration in seconds how long each picture is shown (without the crossfade duration), and "B" is the crossfade duration in seconds.
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -i IMG_%3d.jpg -vf zoompan=d=(A+B)/B:fps=1/B,framerate=25:interp_start=0:interp_end=255:scene=100 -c:v mpeg4 -maxrate 5M -q:v 2 out.mp4
> ```

So, i have these images:

```
$ ls /path/to/test_*.jpg | wc -l
249
```

I'd like framerate to be 25 fps, duration of each image without fade: quarter second, 0.25 sec (so 6.25 frames, or floored, 6 frames), and fade duration 4 frames (so 0.16 sec @ 25 fps). So I'd expect at least 249*(6+4) = 2490 frames, or 99.6 sec at 25 fps.

This is the format of the images (from a phone camera):

```
$ mediainfo /path/to/test_IMG_11a.jpg
General
Complete name                            : /path/to/test_IMG_11a.jpg
Format                                   : JPEG
File size                                : 1 001 KiB

Image
Format                                   : JPEG
Width                                    : 3 840 pixels
Height                                   : 2 160 pixels
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:2
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 1 001 KiB (100%)
```

So, I try this command line:

```
ffmpeg -an -f image2 -pattern_type glob -i '/path/to/test_*.jpg' \
-vf 'fps=25,zoompan=d=(0.25+0.16)/0.16:fps=1/0.16,framerate=25:interp_start=0:interp_end=255:scene=100' \
-vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -level 3 \
-y out.mp4
```

This results with two problems:

---

The first problem is:

```
[swscaler @ 0x5582a63a4500] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
    Last message repeated 3 times
```

While I don't call scale directly, apparently it is implied, because I see in https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/colorspace:

> YUV-to-RGB or scaling requires swscale.

The post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43038294/im-getting-error-deprecated-pixel-format-used-make-sure-you-did-set-range-corr notes this warning can be ignored. However, I'd like to get it right; I've found:

- [[Libav-user] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly](https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/libav-user/2014-March/006371.html)

> But if you use swscale, you also have to be set the range yourself, or the result will be incorrect.

- [Converting yuvj420p to yuv420p - issues with black levels? : ffmpeg](https://www.reddit.com/r/ffmpeg/comments/8t54bm/converting_yuvj420p_to_yuv420p_issues_with_black/) with a "solved" example that uses colorspace

... but I have no idea how to specify colorspace for my images

---

Second problem: not sure if it is related to the first problem, but the output video as result of the above command stops at frame=  421 - and I can see, most of my 249 images are not encoded! Vlc sees some 16 seconds in the output video - way below the 2490 frames, or 99.6 sec, that I expect.

---

So, what is the correct command line invocation, to get a slide show from image sequence with fade, without the deprecation warnings and with all images encoded?

Comment: Remove `-pix_fmt yuv420p` and place it within your filterchain as the first filter: `-vf 'format=yuv420p,...`. You may still get the "`deprecated pixel format`" message that you can ignore, but it will only show up once and not spam the console. I recommend always using format instead of `-pix_fmt` so you can better control when the format conversion happens in relation to the other filters.

Comment: Thanks @llogan - tried that, `deprecated pixel format` still appears throughout the entire run (though seemingly somewhat less often), and unfortunately the video is still truncated (that is, just 421 frames in output video, instead of expected 2k+)

Comment: [Download](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) or [compile](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) a recent build.

Comment: Same issue for me, latest ffmpeg as of February 28, 2023. I think the zoompan was never meant to do a crossfade.

Comment: I edited that wiki link to denote that the crossfade example is broken

Comment: @llogan Did not help unfortunately, same issues with latest ffmpeg